# Should Image Sitemaps be Supplied to Google?

Tags: seo, sitemap

I hear controversial things regarding image sitemaps.
On Google Webmasters forum people say that submitting a sitemap for images doesn't make sense, because Google won't use it to index images anyway.
On the other hand, Google's Search Engine Optimization
Starter Guide recommends supplying an image sitemap.

Comment: ...and exactly what proof do these people provide for claiming that the sitemap won't do pretty much exactly what Google say it'll do?

Comment: I didn't see any proof there. Just statements. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Google's Search Engine Optimization Starter Guide recommends supplying an image sitemap

There's your answer.

Sitemaps help supply search engines with a quick and easy reference to the content on your website. The more information you can give search engines about your site, the better.

Also read http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=178636 and http://googleimagesitemap.com/

Comment: It's also worth remembering that Google is constantly improving their search engine and adding new ways to rank/index/organize the web. So even assuming that Google doesn't currently use image sitemaps, they could still be planning on using them once more people adopt it, or be in the process of implementing them right now.

Comment: Thank you so very much!
I had read the first article already, that is why I got confused when stumbled upon those comments on the forum after having read Google's article.
And the second one is just priceless - I tried to find a free image sitemap generator in vain, and here it is - simply beautiful. :)
I already set it up and going to start using it.